# RODC and domain database

Tags: database, rodc

Supposed I have 1 domain (in 1 tree 1 forest), say, computer.local.
And 4 DCs:

- DC01, holds all 5 FSMOs
- DC02,
- DC03,
- DC04, RODC.

All of them connected each other.

Suppose I log on to DC02, and run [Active Directory Users and Computers] and add a user.

What I want to know is this.
This new user,

1. Will it be written to DC02 harddisk first then replicated to the other 3?
   or
2. This new user record is written in DC01, which holds the PDC role and written to the other computers?

And, what if I log in to DC04 (RODC)?

3. Will it be written to DC04 harddisk first then replicated to the other 3?
   or
4. This new user record is written in DC01, which holds the PDC role and written to the other computers?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, DC04 is an RODC and therefore you will not be creating accounts on it (it will never be written to disk on DC04 first).  Otherwise, it will be written to whichever domain controller ADUC is connected to and will replicate from there.

Comment: Ahh, this is the place. Thanks Katherine for your answer. It helps clear my confusion for a week.